# Remover as datas duplicadas somando os valores

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Preciso remover do dataframe as datas duplicadas e somar os valores correspondentes a essas datas.

Achei uma resposta no stack NA que se aproxima da que eu preciso, mas não consegui moldar para a minha necessidade:

```
df.groupby('data', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.valor.idxmax()])
```

Só que ao invés de agrupar pela data e manter o valor maior, preciso que mantenha a soma dos valores, não somente o valor maior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, então vou responder para ajudar quem tiver de enfrentar o mesmo problema futuramente.

Segue a explicação com o código:

**Gerando o dataframe a partir de um dicionário existente:**

```
swap_df = pd.DataFrame(swap_montado, columns=['Portfolio', 'Data posicao', 'Valor'])
```

**Agrupando os dados a partir da data e somando os valores da serie *Valor* que correspondem às datas DUPLICADAS :**

```
swap_df = swap_df.groupby('Data posicao').agg({
            'Portfolio': 'first',
            'Valor': sum
        })
```

**Reorganizando a ordem das colunas do dataframe:**

```
swap_df = swap_df[['Valor', 'Portfolio']]
```

Resolução encontrada em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403752/pandas-sum-over-duplicated-indices-with-sum